# How to round a float value with button

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa, xcode4

Okay so I'm trying to get my values rounded up to the nearest whole number with an IBAction.

```
So 1.88 -> 2.00 ,  
11.40 -> 12.00 ,   
111.01 -> 112.00, etc.
```

-

```
-(IBAction)roundUp:(id)sender   
{   
    float floatRoundValue=lblTotalRound.text floatValue];
    ceilf(floatRoundValue);
    NSString *stringRoundValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.0f", floatRoundValue];
    lblTotalRound.text=stringRoundValue;
}
```

That's what I got. But it's still rounding down below .5 and to the nearest integer

```
(Ex. 1.19 -> 1 , i need 1.19 -> 2.00).
```

I've tried %1.2f but the value doesnt change at all.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ceilf is a function that returns a value (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man3/ceil.3.html) , you simply need to change that line to the following.

```
floatRoundValue = ceilf(floatRoundValue);
```

So the complete code would in your case it would be something like this.

```
-(IBAction)roundUp:(id)sender   
{   
    float floatRoundValue=lblTotalRound.text floatValue];
    floatRoundValue = ceilf(floatRoundValue);
    NSString *stringRoundValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.0f", floatRoundValue];
    lblTotalRound.text=stringRoundValue;
}
```

Comment: Yup that works! Thanks. but one more question  how would I put a $ sign in front of my values without going the whole NumberFormatter route? (Ex. 1.88 -> $1.88)

Comment: As Kurt Revis suggested above, use stringWithFormat which is a very powerful tool. Just insert your dollar sign into the string like this "$%1.0f".

Answer (score 2):

`ceilf` doesn't modify the value you pass in. It *returns* a modified value.

```
floatRoundValue = ceilf(floatRoundValue);
```

Comment: Ah okay, that makes sense. Thanks. I was so close haha

Comment: Also how would I put a $ sign in front of my values? (Ex. 1.88 -> $1.88)

Comment: Put the `$` in the format string. Look up the documentation for `-[NSString stringWithFormat:]` to understand how it works.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to have a $ sign before :

```
-(IBAction)roundUp:(id)sender   
{   
    float floatRoundValue=(lblTotalRound.text floatValue]; 
    floatRoundValue = ceilf(floatRoundValue);
    NSString *stringRoundValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%1.0f", floatRoundValue];
    lblTotalRound.text=stringRoundValue;
}
```

[NSString Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)